# .Net 6.0 Framework missing in Visual Studio 2022 v17.3.1

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

I have installed .NET 6.0 SDK and Visual Studio 2022 v17.3.1. However, Visual Studio 2022 does not offer the ability to select .NET 6.0, nor does the Visual Studio Installer.

Images:

[installed .Net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGExH.png)

[packages in Installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPKdo.png)

[.Net's in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxRzm.png)

I reinstalled VS two times and .Net 6.0 SDK with no effects. It seems like only .Net 6.0 runtime is available, but not the framework.

All I want to do is to upgrade c# to version 10. If i'm doing something wrong, please let me know

Comment: Similar to the linked thread, you misunderstood what is .NET 5/6/7. They (.NET 5/6/7) are not upgrades of .NET Framework, but .NET Core, so you won't see them listed for a .NET Framework project.

Comment: So how can I upgrade my project to c# v10?

Comment: You have to migrate from .NET Framework to .NET Core, or you are restricted to C# 7.3, because C# 8.0 and above are not supported on .NET Framework if you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8 "C# 8.0 is supported on .NET Core 3.x and .NET Standard 2.1."

Comment: Okay, this is already very helpful. But are there class liberies for .Net core?

Comment: Migration to .NET Core varies a lot on different code bases, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/ You can do it yourself or hire someone else. I don't think Stack Overflow can help too much unless you are asking a more specific question.